# How to use git clean remove all file list in .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-clean

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
mkdir temp
touch temp/in.tmp
touch out.tmp
echo '*tmp' > .gitignore
```

when use `git clean -Xn` it show `Would remove out.tmp`

but I want to remove `temp/in.tmp` together

`git clean -Xdn` not work too, but `cd` to `temp` directory and run `git clean -Xn` it show `Would remove in.tmp`

so I wonder is there a command to remove all file list in `.gitignore` include  subdirectory, in this case how to use `git clean` remove `temp/in.tmp` and `out.tmp`

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

---

I found something weird

add a file in `temp` directory and stage it , `git clean -Xn` seems work

```
touch temp/a.txt
git add temp/a.txt
git clean -Xn
```

it show

```
Would remove out.tmp
Would remove temp/in.tmp
```

but why that happend ?

Comment: Weird. docs say *Cleans the working tree by **recursively** removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.*

Comment: A wild guess: Git only traverses directories in the index with the `-X` option, ignoring the `temp` directory (because it initially doesn't know it, only after you add a file). I can replicate the issue with Git 2.1.4 on Ubuntu. Why don't you ask this at git@vger.kernel.org?

Answer (score 10):

You need `-x` because you want to delete file ignored by `.gitignore`

`git clean -fdx`

will successufully clean everything for you

`macsp:repo proto$ git clean -fdxn
Would remove .gitignore
Would remove out.tmp
Would remove temp/
macsp:repo proto$`

Comment: but `-x` also removing all untracked files

Comment: Ok I see you point. You want to delete all files that match the .gitignore but do not delete all the other untracked files. I think this problem you have is really a corner case due to the fact that git does not track empty folders.

Comment: I'm working on a CLI called gnore that should solve this, as well as add a bunch of other goodies